# iPad app cache all pages

Tags: ios, ipad, caching, cache-manifest

I'm currently working on an offline web app for the iPad. I have set up the offline cache manifest and have tested to ensure that it is caching properly (which it is). However when trying to navigate through the web app offline (airplane mode) it throws up an error and closes the app.

Does the manifest cache ALL pages or only the pages you navigate to before turning offline? I'm suspecting that it isn't caching all pages and wondered if you guys had any similar issues?

Thanks

Carl

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that apache htpasswd affects how offline caching works so you need to turn this off.